# Отметить чекбокс jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Я пытаюсь отметить чекбокс при нажатии, использую атрибут `checked`. Например если стоит галочка для атрибута Возраст, то появляется поле ввода возраста.

Но приведенный ниже код всегда возвращает `false`

```
if($('#isAgeSelected').attr('checked')) {
    $("#txtAge").show();
} else {
    $("#txtAge").hide();
}
```

Как правильно проверить отмеченность чекбокса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#isAgeSelected').is(':checked');
```

Answer (score 5):

Проверяйте не атрибут, а свойство checkbox элемента:

```
if ($('#isAgeSelected').prop('checked')) {
    // ...
}
```

Что будет альтернативно следующему на чистом JavaScript:

```
if (document.getElementById('isAgeSelected').checked) {
    // ...
}
```

Этот вариант будет исполняться максимально быстро.

---

Кроме того, ваш код можно переписать в одну строку:

```
$("#txtAge").toggle($('#isAgeSelected').prop('checked'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Eщё есть вариант слегка костыльный, но может пригодится в других задачах

```
if ($('#isAgeSelected:checked').length > 0) {
  ...
}
```

но в данном случае `prop` или `isChecked` лучше.